# Magento Swapping Customer Orders and Billing Information

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, customer-account

We have a Magento website that is experience this issue. When a customer places an order on our website in their account, after the order goes through it is showing the billing address for a different customer in the confirmation. The billing information that it shows is for a completely different customer with a separate account. This has caused us to send several orders out to the wrong addresses. Has anyone experienced this before? Any ideas to fix it?

Also, when the customer logs into their account it is showing the information from a different customer.

We have tried running a cron job daily and that seemed to fix the issue for a week, but then it happened again twice yesterday and today. Our website is using Magento ver. 1.7.0.0

Thank you!